# Deploy a universal APP made with Nuxtjs on apache shared hosting

Tags: apache, nuxt.js

I just finished a universal app developed with Nuxtjs and want to deploy it on the server of the company where i work. I have to say that i'm pretty newbie with server things, so i'm kinda lost here.

The specs of the server are the following:

[image]

Most of the tutorials talk about proxying with Nginx, that's what i did first, but to do so i killed the apache server that was using que port 80 (I didn't know i was doing that), so i mounted the apache server again and
gave up with nginx.

Then i found an .htaccess file on the web and tryed it out, the file had the following code:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

It didn't work at all

Then i tryed writing the next two lines on the httpd.conf file of the apache (I found them two on another tutorial).

```
ProxyPass "https://appdomain.tk" "http://localhost:3000"
ProxyPassReverse "https://appdomain.tk" "http://localhost:3000"
```

They didn't work either. I'm loosing my mind.
I have the ssl certificate configured for the domain, and a free domain .tk

Is there actually a way to deploy a universal Nuxt.js app on an apache shared hosting?

Answer (score 7):

I make something like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/YOUR_DIR"
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

of course you should also run in apache proxy. If you do not have it enabled, execute the command:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

and restart apache, run node app.

Comment: Seting ServerName and ServerAlias won't afect all other sites hosted? what should i specifically write on DocumentRoot? my node app is hosted at /home/myuser/public_html

Comment: this configuration is based on separating the project through the YOUR_DIR directory. "ProxyPass /" indicates the root of the document. I am not sure if it will work, but you can try to create "/YOUR_DIR/APP" directory and set Proxy on "/APP". Maybe it will help. I configure on my VPS

Comment: the question is how do you want to run node applications on shared hosting? do you have access to SSH?

Comment: Yes, i do hace access to SSH and also an acount to access to /home/myuser/

Comment: @JanuszO Can you please confirm, can we configure and access it on IP-URL instead of a domain?